# Highlight cell rows on selection error

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code for my Excel worksheet. It highlights the table rows by the row you have selected but problems arise if you highlight cells in the table to the outside or you put a slicer in the table. Here it the Module I use:

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub HighlightTableRow(Target As Excel.Range)

Dim t As ListObject
Dim lngInTable As Long
Dim c As Long

Const COLOR_SELECT = xlThemeColorAccent1
Const COLOR_LIGHTER = 0.4

On Error Resume Next

If Target.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternSolid Then Exit Sub

For Each t In Target.Parent.ListObjects
    c = c + 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, t.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        lngInTable = c
    End If
    t.Range.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
Next
If lngInTable = 0 Then Exit Sub

With Target.Parent.ListObjects(lngInTable)
    With .Range.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With .DataBodyRange
        With .Resize(Target.Rows.Count).Offset(Target.Row - .Row).Interior
            .ThemeColor = COLOR_SELECT
            .TintAndShade = 1 - COLOR_LIGHTER
        End With
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

And I put this code in each Excel sheet so the code works:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
HighlightTableRow Target
End Sub
```

I have no idea how to fix this error. The formatting gets weird. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI- You'll likely get more hits if you add the tag VBS or VBA.

Comment: this has nearly nothing to do with VBS...

Comment: I tried fixing this on my own but still nothing... lol